# Is it possible to put password on export from phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Please let me know that is it possible that i put a password on "export" from phpmyadmin?
I use share hosting.

Comment: I log in with my pass to phpmyadmin ,but for security i would like that put a pass on "export" so if a people access to main pass don't access for exporting my db.